# I want to display image after uploading file

Tags: php

the update part is working good but it is not diplaying the upload image

```html
<?php
Session_Start();
$target_dir = "/var/www/html/";
 //the update part is working good but it is not diplaying the upload image 
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
checking the target directory in server
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]); 
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 50000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $File_Name=  basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
     echo $File_Name; 
$image=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]; /* Displaying Image*/
  
  echo '<img src= "$.image.">';  i want to displaying but it is not displaying the image 
 
$_SESSION['File_Name'] = $File_Name;

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';       
     
function Link1()      
{      
if(document.Form1.checkbox1.checked == true)      
{      
alert("Want to Add Some More Medicines.");  
 location.href="products.php"; 
}      
}      
function Link2()      
{      
if(document.Form1.checkbox2.checked == true)      
{      
alert("You have clicked on Make Delivery At Home."); 
location.href="billing.php";      
}      
} 
       
</script>';


  

echo "<form name='Form1' style='color: green ; font-size: 150%' action = '#'> 
 <input type='radio' name='checkbox1' value='' onclick = 'Link1()'  />Want to Add Some More Medicines<br>
 <input type='radio' name='checkbox2' value='' onclick = 'Link2()'  />Make Delivery At Home<br>
</form>";

         

    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file."; 
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: The check and everything after is outside the `if` statement. Put it inside the if statement.

Comment: only the image is not displaying could you plze check it out the portion "<img src>"

Comment: Try passing ``$target_file`` in image src.

Comment: it is working can anyone help me out

Comment: i had tried wtih little more stuff but still it is not showing image

Comment: can any one can help me out with this code i tried it very much